# How to use SQL syntax in Oracle fast formula

Tags: oracle, performance, formula, oracle-apps

I want to use extract(DAY from date) function in [Oracle FastFormula](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/per/ffugax.htm). However I am getting error when I used above. Is there a similar seeded functionality that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: What does "fast formula" mean?  What error are you getting?  How do you define "seeded functionality"?

Comment: fast formula in Oracle EBS. and meant by seeded functionality like to_char(date)

Comment: also found a solution can use to_char(date,'DD') to get the day in a date in fast formula.

Comment: Post exactly what you're doing (i.e. actual code), and exactly what error you're getting, otherwise we have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: [Oracle FastFormula](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/per/ffugax.htm) is not a very popular technology. I took the liberty to edit your question to add the relevant link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [function reference for OracleFormula](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e14567/T1774T1776.htm#d0e4402), it seems that you have no other option than calling `TO_CHAR` with the appropriate format to achieve the desired result. based on the doc's example:

```
     mesg = 'Birthday is: ' + TO_CHAR (birthdate,
            'DD')
```